# Find radius of convergence of power series: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^{2n} / (2n)!$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

We have the power series $ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} z^{2n}$. How do I get the $c_n$ to use the formula: $C= \lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|c_n|}{|c_{n+1}|}$ ?

I don't know if I can use $\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}$ as $c_n$ because $z$ has $2n$ in the exponent.

Can I transform the series to this form: $ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n$ ?

Comment: Let $c_n=\frac{{(-1)}^n}{(2n)!}z^{2n}$? Then $c_{n+1}=\frac{{(-1)}^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!}z^{2(n+1)}$

Comment: How can i get the series above in this form: $ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n$?

Comment: @Shuri2060 I dont think its correct to use z in the formula.

Comment: Moreover, you could recognize a very well known Taylor series.

Comment: Didn't introduced yet.

Comment: @Maddude my bad - I'd assumed you were using the ratio test like in Salahamam_Fatima's answer

Comment: @Maddude, the "shortcut" method that you talked about using in your question does not use $z$.  But the "longer" way -- which is actually just the ratio test -- is supposed to include $z$.  And for this you need to include the $z$ because you need to do the ratio test, and you need to do the ratio test because the exponent is $2n$.

Comment: What about using "Hadamard" definition?

Comment: @Maddude Eh.  Whether or not you use $z$ in the formula, the result is practically the same, if interpreted correctly.

Comment: @Maddude You mean the root test?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also straightforward by "definition" of the radius of convergence, since $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\lim \frac{1}{\sqrt[2n]{(2n)!}}$, and $\sqrt[2n]{(2n)!} \to + \infty$, which can be seen by the inequality
\begin{align*}
\sqrt[2n]{(2n)!} &\geq \sqrt[2n]{\left(\frac{2n}{2}\right)^n} \\
&=n^{1/2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Why is $\limsup\sqrt[n]{|c_n|}=\lim \sqrt[2n]{(2n)!}$ ?

Comment: @Maddude If you see the series as a "full" power series with coefficients on every $z^n$, then you have that $c_n$ is alternating between $0$ on the odd numbers and $\frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{n!}$ on the even numbers.

Comment: Taking Hadamard *characterization* of the radius of convergence for its *definition*? What a bad idea. (Yes, I am sure some curricula are making this dreadful choice, do not get me started on this topic...)

Comment: @Did I think the quotation marks imply (quite heavily) that I agree with you on the misnomer, although not so heavily as to make such a patronizing comment. So, what is the purpose of the comment?

Comment: You are seeing patronizing comments where there are none. Let us return to the **maths**: why use the word definition if you are aware this is no definition (and if you are aware that at least half of mse users believe it is)? I did not get the quotes were supposed to mean that the word definition is referring to something that is not a definition and I doubt many users got that either... I hope the purpose of my first comment is clearer to you now.

Answer (score 3):

Use d'Alembert classical ratio  test.

Let $u_n(z)=\frac {(-1)^nz^{2n}}{(2n)!} $.

$$\lim_{+\infty}\frac {|u_{n+1}(z)|}{|u_n(z)|}=$$

$$=\lim_{+\infty}\frac {|z|^2}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}=0$$

the series is absolutely convergent for all complex numbers $z $.

the radius is infinite.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}u_n(z)=\cos (z) $$

Comment: Can I transform the series to this form: $ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n$ ?

Comment: @Maddude yes with a=0 and c_{2n+1}=0.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z^2=y .$ Then by the ratio test the series converges for all $y,$ hence for all $z.$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the "shortcut" method isn't safe to use.

Simple example of it failing:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(\frac x2\right)^{2n} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(\frac{x^2}4\right)^n$ is a geometric series which converges for $x^2/4 < 1$, i.e., for $|x| < 2$.

If we rewrite the series as $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac1{4^n} x^{2n}$ then we can try using the "shortcut" method with $c_n = \dfrac 1{4^n}$ and $c_{n+1} = \dfrac1{4^{n+1}}$.  This will give us $$C = \lim_{n\to+\infty}\left|\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right| = \lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{4^{n+1}}{4^n} = 4.$$
This means the radius of convergence is $4$, but this is most certainly not the case since $|x| < 2$ means the radius of convergence is $2$.

Now, this doesn't mean that the "shortcut" method will **always** fail when the exponent on the variable is $an$ for some $a \ne 1$.  It just means that it doesn't always work, and if it doesn't always work for a certain case, then don't use it in those cases.  It's better to use something that we know works 100% of the time in those cases.  And in this case, the thing to use is the standard ratio test.

For your specific example, let $a_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} z^{2n}$.  Then find $a_{n+1}$ and then find the values of $z$ that satisfy $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| < 1.$  (This was worked out in the other answer.)  I also encourage you to try the "shortcut" method on this to see what happens.

> Can I transform the series to this form: $ \sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty c_n(z-a)^n$ ?

Not in a useful way.  If you do this then you'll have $a = 0$ (which is fine), and $$c_n = \begin{cases} 1/n!, & \text{if } n \bmod 4 = 0, \\ -1/n!, & \text{if } n \bmod 4 = 2, \\ 0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}. \end{cases}$$

This form of $c_n$ is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test handles this:
\begin{align}
& \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left| \dfrac{(-1)^{n+1} z^{2(n+1)}}{(2(n+1))!} \right|}{\left| \dfrac{(-1)^n z^{2n}}{(2n)!} \right|} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n)!|z^2|}{(2(n+1))!} \\[12pt]
={} & |z^2| \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(2n+2)!} \quad \text{This step is posssible because $|z^2|$ does not change as $n$  changes.} \\[12pt]
= {} & |z^2| \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)!(2n+1)(2n+2)} = |z^2| \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac 1 {(2n+1)(2n+2)} \\[12pt]
= {} & 0 \text{ regardless of what number $|z^2|$ is.}
\end{align}
Therefore the series converges regardless of how big $|z|$ is. The radius of convergence is infinite.